# Run batch script from python, to kill python?

Tags: python, batch-file, kill

I want to run a batch script from a python script, and I want it to kill the python script when done. The problem is, whenever the batch script is run from python, it doesn't kill python.

in the batch file(dl.bat):

```
Taskkill /F /IM python.exe
```

python:

```
call("dl.bat")
```

Comment: If you just want to exit the python script, try looking at sys.exit()

Comment: I agree with above, for any reason when running the actual python you want to quit, simply exit() will do.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Taskkill /F /IM python.exe /T
```

/T                     Terminates the specified process and any
                         child processes which were started by it.